# Send Array of hashes to class to create a user from each

Tags: arrays, ruby, ruby-hash

I have a array of hashes

```
pets = [
    {
    "firstName": "Brianna",
     "lastName": "Parson",
     "children": ["sam","Joe"],
     "buddys": {
     
    },
     
    {
     "firstName": "jeffery",
     "lastName": "thomas",
     
     }
     }
    ]
```

How do you send a class an array of hashes?

Comment: Why not just iterate over the array of hashes and output the information the way you want? Why both creating `User` objects for each hash?

Answer (score 2):

You don't need anything that initialize method.I passed the hash the initialize method

```rb
  def initialize(user)
    @users = user
  end
```

And also As you realized that, the users information in an array, so firstly, you should loop through the array and you should take all hash information with hash syntax.

```rb
 def show_userhash
    @users.each do |user|
      puts "#{user[:firstName]} is a #{user[:job]} also has #{user[:pets].length} #{pet_num = user[:pets].length == 1 ? "pet" : "pets"} "
    end
  end
```

When you made an instance of a class with a new method, first, the initialize method will execute and then, you should invoke the `show_userhash` method.

Here is the full code.

```rb
class Person

  def initialize(user)
    @users = user
  end

  def show_userhash
    @users.each do |user|
      puts "#{user[:firstName]} is a #{user[:job]} also has #{user[:pets].length} #{pet_num = user[:pets].length == 1 ? "pet" : "pets"} "
    end
  end
end

person_information  = [
      {
        "firstName": "Brianna",
        "lastName": "Parson",
        "job": "SOFTWARE ENGINEER",
        "totalAssetWorth": "2000.00",
        "totalDebt": "1500.00",
        "children": ["sam", "Joe"],
        "pets": {
          "dog": "jeff",
          "bird": "zoe"
        }
      },

      {
        "firstName": "Jeffery",
        "lastName": "thomas",
        "job": "Lawyer",
        "totalAssetWorth": "6000.00",
        "totalDebt": "1300.00",
        "children": [],
        "pets": {
          "cat": "gnocchi"
        }
      }
    ]
intro = Person.new(person_information)
intro.show_userhash
```

Comment: I have changed the code. I hope you mean that. @CarySwoveland

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this

```
users = [
  {
    "firstName": "Brianna",
    "lastName": "Parson",
    "job": "SOFTWARE ENGINEER",
    "totalAssetWorth": "2000.00",
    "totalDebt": "1500.00",
    "children": ["sam","Joe"],
    "pets": {
      "dog": "jeff",
      "bird": "zoe"
    } 
  },
  {
    "firstName": "jeffery",
    "lastName": "thomas",
    "job": "Lawyer",
    "totalAssetWorth": "6000.00",
    "totalDebt": "1300.00",
    "children": [],
    "pets": {
      "cat": "gnocchi"
    }
  }
]
```

```
class User
  def initialize(args)
    @first_name = args[:firstName].capitalize
    @last_name = args[:lastName].capitalize
    @job = args[:job].downcase
    @total_asset_worth = args[:totalAssetWorth].to_f
    @total_debt = args[:totalDebt]
    @children = args[:children]
    @pets = args[:pets]
  end

  def to_s
    "#{@first_name} is a #{@job} and has #{@children.count} children and #{@pets.count} pet"
  end
end
```

```
puts users.map { |args| User.new(args) }

# Brianna is a software engineer and has 2 children and 2 pet
# Jeffery is a lawyer and has 0 children and 1 pet
```

Some Ruby magic: when pass array to `puts` method, each element will be put on new line and `to_s` method will be applied

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple class.

```rb
class Person
  def initialize(full_name, job, num_children, num_pets)
    @full_name = full_name
    @job = job
    @num_children = num_children
    @num_pets = num_pets
  end
  
  def to_s
    format(
      '%s is a %s and has %d children and %d pets',
      @full_name,
      @job,
      @num_children,
      @num_pets
    )
  end
end
```

This is just an example. Your final class design will depend on your application.

See http://ruby-doc.com/docs/ProgrammingRuby/ for a more complete introduction to classes.